# Boot Kali persistent USB directly, skipping the menu

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, grub

I want to boot my PC with the Kali persistence USB directly by skipping the Kali Linux default boot menu. The BIOS is set to start from USB. When I boot, the Kali boot menu is showing normally.

How do I skip the menu and boot directly into Kali?

My OS info:
`Linux linux 4.14.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.12-2kali1 (2018-01-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: It’s not entirely clear to me that this question is even *about* Kali.  IMHO, it would have been more appropriate to close it as “Unclear what you’re asking”, “Too broad” (lack of research), or “Off-topic” (belongs on [SU]).  But, yeah, it’s true: anybody who has the skills and knowledge to be running Kali on a real machine shouldn’t be asking questions like this.

Comment: how its broad? Its very simple to understand that which file has to be edit to not show default kali boot screen and directly boot from persistence usb. Where you are not understanding?

Comment: Phrases sometimes take on idiomatic meanings.  On [SE], “too broad” sometimes means ‘‘you haven’t tried hard enough to find an answer to this question simply by doing research and experimentation.’’

Comment: “It’s very simple to understand” — no.  What’s on the computer now?  You call it a “windows pc” (which, BTW, should be capitalized: “Windows PC”) and yet you talk about a “Kali default meny” (by which I guess you mean “menu”).  Why are you getting a Kali menu from a Windows PC?  Is it multi-boot?  What operating systems?  Why is your question tagged [ubuntu]?  Or is Kali on the USB device?  (If not, what is?)  Exactly what menu are you getting?  What do your BIOS boot settings say?  … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott I updated my question

Comment: Your original question was incomprehensible because you gave too little information and some of it was misleading (“windows pc”, but Windows is irrelevant since you're booting Linux). Your edited question was hard to understand because it contained the necessary information, but badly worded and hidden inside a lot of irrelevant informaion. When you ask a question, write it down, then blank your mind, and put yourself in the readers' mind. Ask yourself: Does the _question_ have all the necessary information? Is it comprehensible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: I understand this question exactly.  As it comes, when Kali boots it presents a menu and sits there waiting for you to do something.  If every time you want to select the same item off the menu, how do you get it to make that selection automatically (optionally after so many seconds of delay).

Answer (score 1):

If you

- make your Kali persistent live with the tool [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb),
- select 'usb-pack-efi' in the settings menu (please notice that you will boot 'as debian' with user:'user' and password:'live' and need `sudo` for system tasks),

assuming the persistent live drive is `/dev/sdc`,

<sup>Please check this for example with `sudo lsblk -f` or `sudo parted -ls` and modify if necessary, for example from `/dev/sdc3` to `/dev/sdb3` or `/dev/sdd3` in the following mount command line</sup>

you can

- mount the third partition on the USB drive

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sd3
  sudo mount -rw /dev/sdc3 /mnt/sd3
  ```
- backup the original `grub.cfg`

  ```
  sudo cp /mnt/sd3/boot/grub/grub.cfg /mnt/sd3/boot/grub/grub.cfg.orig
  ```
- and edit the first line in `grub.cfg`

  ```
  sudo nano /mnt/sd3/boot/grub/grub.cfg
  ```

  to change it from `set timeout=10` to `set timeout=0`

This will make Kali skip the grub menu and go directly to the desktop environment.

---

I tested that it works with the iso file `kali-linux-light-2017.3-amd64.iso`

Comment: It isn't recommended to edit `grub.cfg` directly as the consequences of mistakes can be difficult to recover unless you know what you are doing. Better to edit `/etc/default/grub` then `update-grub`. Also i doesn't 'skip' anything, just makes it zero length as far as the user is concerned.

Comment: @bu5hman, This is a persistent live system (not a standard installed system). This is a special tweak. Your advice is generally good but I think in this case it is a good idea to edit `grub.cfg`. In order to make things safer, I will edit my answer and recommend a backup copy of the original grub.cfg.

Comment: I stand corrected! And in the end, a live boot of Kali with no mission critical data on a USB has no real value.

Comment: I am unable to find grub.cfg even I located but not exists. Linux linux 4.14.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.12-2kali1 (2018-01-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Raakh, Did you create the persistent live drive with mkusb? In that case you should find it where I describe it in the answer. Otherwise, with another tool to create a persistent live drive, you may find it somewhere else or not at all, if there is only a syslinux boot system.

Comment: @Raakh, In the answer I assume that the persistent live drive is `/dev/sdc`. Please check this for example with `sudo lsblk -f` or `sudo parted -ls` and modify if necessary.

Comment: I changed but main problem is there is no grub.cfg file

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the output of the following two commands in order to identify the persistent live drive and its partitions, `sudo lsblk -f` and  `sudo parted -ls`

Comment: Did you select 'usb-pack-efi' in the settings menu of mkusb?

Comment: @Raakh, I understand that you cannot find the grub.cfg file. But there is not enough detailed information for me to understand why. Please *help me* by answering all my questions and giving the details, that I need, *and I will help you* solve your problem.

Comment: @sudodus please let me know what information you need?

Comment: 1. Did you create the persistent live drive with mkusb? 2. Please run the following 3 command lines and add the output in your original question. Indent each line 4 spaces to render the output as 'code' (easier to read), `sudo lsblk -f` and  `sudo parted -ls` and `df` ; 3. If you used mkusb, did  you select 'usb-pack-efi' in the settings menu of mkusb?